# How to drop oracle user starting with colon (:)

Tags: oracle, special-characters

I've used impdp and had a typo - now I've got a user name starting with colon (:) - e.g :my_schema.

How can I drop this user? I've tried everything I could think of to escape it, but nothing helps.

Edit: To clarify - I know how to drop a user. I'm having difficulty overcoming the special character issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can do this with dynamic SQL:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'create user ":MY_SCHEMA" identified by xxx';
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select username, account_status from dba_users where username = ':MY_SCHEMA';

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------
:MY_SCHEMA                     OPEN

begin
    execute immediate 'drop user ":MY_SCHEMA"';
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select username, account_status from dba_users where username = ':MY_SCHEMA';

no rows selected
```

Comment: This worked for me for a similar problem of dropping a procedure with a special character in the name.

Comment: @Jeff - you'd just need to enclose the name in double quotes in that case ([see the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/sql_elements008.htm)) but in static SQL; the dynamic part here is specifically for the user name. This works but is slight overkill for a procedure or other object with a quoted identifier.

Comment: I tried double quotes in a static statement and it still blew up. It didn't make sense to me either, but the dynamic worked and I was grateful to find something that worked. My procedure had hyphens and ended with a question mark character. (I'd renamed it with the ending "--can delete?" then I couldn't delete it. The irony!)

Answer (score 4):

Did you try enclosing it in double quotes?  e.g

```
drop user ":my_schema";
```

The case is important when you do this - is it ":myschema" or ":MYSCHEMA" or something in between?

Answer (score 1):

I never managed to do this, had to restore from backups.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use:

```
drop user :my_schema;
```

or

```
drop user :my_schema cascade;
```

if the user has constraints in other tables then they will not be removed.

```
drop table x cascade constraints; etc.
```

the only problem there is that you loose everything and have to start over. If you database has a script then you just to need to re run the script to reload it in.

Comment: I know how to drop a user - I'm having problem with the colon at the start - it's a special char

Comment: @Ran Biron I see, I will keep trying to find a solution to the problem. If i come across anything I will make sure to post it.